# Only undo last input, without Blender going overboard

Tags: modeling

There are Blender operations that opens up a settings window in the bottom left, such as when doing a Bevel operation.

[image: Blender Bevel Tool]

If I edit a value, say I edit the width, the number of segments and the profile type, then I sometimes want to undo an edit. For instance, I think "maybe it looks better with a width of 1.5m". So I test that, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> if I dislike it.

*Problem:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> closes the window and undoes the entire operation.
How do I convince Blender to only undo my last text input/last specific action?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because changing an operator's setting isn't an operation, hence isn't undoable.

You could use a modifier instead.